# Set a domain on a field depending on the value of another field in the formView:Odoo 10

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-10

I have Three Classes :

```
class My_module_C(models.Model):
    _name = 'mymodule.c'
    name = fields.Char(description="Name")


class My_module_B(models.Model):
        _name = 'mymodule.c'
        name = fields.Char(description="Name")
        field_c_ids = fields.Many2many('mymodule.c')



class My_module_A(models.Model):
            _name = 'mymodule.a'
            field_c_id = fields.Many2one('mymodule.c')
            field_b_id = fields.Many2many('mymodule.b')
```

In ModuleA FormView & After the user selects the "field_c_id", i need to filter "field_b_id" in order to show only records with 'mymodule.a.field_c_id' in 'mymodule.b.field_c_ids'
I know i have to @api.onchage('fieldc_id') but i don't know how to return a domain and apply it on the field, any help ?

EDIT :
I found a solution, which is : adding the domain for the field in the xml file :

```
domain=" [('field_c_ids.id', '=', field_c)]"
```

But seriously i have no idea how this logically works, i would rather put :

```
domain=" [(field_c, 'in', 'field_c_ids.ids')]"
```

Can anybody explains to me how it does work?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply domain dynamically by this way.

```
@api.multi
@api.onchange('field_c_id')
def onchange_field_c(self):
    res = {}
    if self.field_c_id:
        domain = {'field_b_id':  [('field_c_ids', 'in', self.field_c_id)]}
        return {'domain': domain}
    return res
```